# How to take cosine squared of raster using python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, raster, arcgis-10.2, mathematics

I have an equation `y = cos^2(x)` where x is a raster.

How can I write this equation in python?

Comment: Really? What is wrong with `cos(x)*cos(x)`? You could use a variable to avoid double computation or `pow` or `**` to raise it to a power directly. Look at the math module.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx I didn't think of cos(x)*cos(x), I've been a few years without math experience... I tried the ** operator but it didn't work. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You need to use ** after the function arguments, not before as in math notation, eg. `math.cos(x)**2`.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx you actually provide the solution, so you could write your comment as an answer.

Comment: Just make sure first to convert the raster values to radians if they are not already expressed in radians.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution is using the `**` exponentiation operator, but you could also use temporary variables or `math.pow`:

```
y = math.cos(x) ** 2
y = math.pow(cos(x), 2)
```

There may be a small speed difference between the two, so run a test for the best if you'll be calculating it for millions of cells. And as whuber noted, make sure the input values are in the right angular format.

Answer (score 2):

Can't get much easier than numpy:

```
gridz = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
np.cos(gridz) ** 2
array([[ 1.        ,  0.29192658,  0.17317819,  0.98008514,  0.42724998],
       [ 1.        ,  0.29192658,  0.17317819,  0.98008514,  0.42724998],
       [ 1.        ,  0.29192658,  0.17317819,  0.98008514,  0.42724998],
       [ 1.        ,  0.29192658,  0.17317819,  0.98008514,  0.42724998],
       [ 1.        ,  0.29192658,  0.17317819,  0.98008514,  0.42724998]])
```